# Database table does not update

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, express

***it doesn't show any error but database table doesn't update***

`id` and `status` taken from HTML form

```
router.get('/update_todo/:todo_id',async function(req,res){
const id = req.body.todo_id;
const status = req.body.complete;
const queryString = "UPDATE todos SET completed = ? WHERE todo_id = ?";
con.query(queryString,[id,status],function(err,rows,fields){
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err.message)
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Updated successfull")
         
    }
})
```

})

my output gives

```
fieldCount  0
affectedRows    0
insertId    0
serverStatus    2
warningCount    0
message "(Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0"
protocol41  true
changedRows 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do, you have to change the sequence of array member in array to `[status, id]` from `[id,status]`

And also as mentioned by Robert Kawecki, your request has to be a `POST` request to fetch `status` value from the body.

```
router.post('/update_todo/:todo_id',async function(req,res){
    const id = req.params.todo_id;
    const status = req.body.complete;
    const queryString = "UPDATE todos SET completed = ? WHERE todo_id = ?";
    con.query(queryString,[status, id],function(err,rows,fields){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err.message)
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Updated successfull")
         
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This still won't work - GET requests don't have a body. There are multiple issues with the original code snippet.

Comment: You are right @RobertKawecki , I am going to edit my answer.